# autoFocus in TextInput but dismiss keyboard in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I want to autoFocus a TextInput (using autoFocus property) BUT keep the keyboard off by default, and only by clicking the TextInput to show the keyboard.

in this situation, I'm trying to make a placeholder and a title for a TextInput but show the full screen without the keyboard, until the user clicks the TextInput.

how can I manage it properly?

Thanks.

Comment: you can use 
**import {Keyboard} from 'react-native'**
**Keyboard.dismiss()**
method after focusing the textinput

Comment: tried to do that, but it unfocused the textinput.

Comment: did you try that in **onFocus** of textinput

Comment: It's seems open keyboard is bind with on focus, couldn't hide the keyboard and focus in the same time. But if you could trigger hardware back button on Android after on focus, maybe could achieve it.